# Как опустить кнопку "Скрыть" в спойлере, что бы она ездила под скрытым контентом

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть задача, отредактировать слайдер. Кнопка SHOW/HIDE расположена вверху справа, а нужно что бы она была расположена внизу, и когда нажимаешь на SHOW, скрытый контент открывается-едет вниз, а кнопка едет вниз под контентом. Когда меняю div местами, перестаёт спускаться (открываться) скрытый контент. Вот данный слайдер:

```js
< script > $(".box .block").show();
$(".closed .block").hide();

$("div.hide").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("show").next().slideToggle("medium");
}); < /script>
```

```css
.box {
  background: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #DCDCDC inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #DCDCDC inset;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #DCDCDC inset;
}
.box h2 {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #444;
  background: #ddd;
  margin: 0 -10px -1px -10px;
  padding: 12px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 45px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #DCDCDC inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #DCDCDC inset;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #DCDCDC inset;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
.block {
  padding: 0;
}
.block_in {
  padding: 12px;
}
.box div.hide {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  line-height: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid 1px #aaa;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px #DCDCDC inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px #DCDCDC inset;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px #DCDCDC inset;
}
.box div.hide:hover {
  background: #fff;
}
.box div.hide span.h {
  display: block;
}
.box div.hide span.s {
  display: none;
}
.box div.show span.h {
  display: none;
}
.box div.show span.s {
  display: block;
}
.closed div.hide span.h {
  display: none;
}
.closed div.hide span.s {
  display: block;
}
.closed div.show span.h {
  display: block;
}
.closed div.show span.s {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="box closed">
  <h2>
                    Toggle (переключатель)
                    <span class="l"></span><span class="r"></span>
                </h2>
  <div class="hide"><span class="s">Show</span><span class="h">Hide</span>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="block_in">
      Контент 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".hide").click(function() {
  var c = $(this);
  $('.block').slideToggle("medium");
  c.toggleClass('show');
});
```